# Azure scaleset storage | update app code | Add an existing VM to a new scale-set

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm

I have three questions that I couldn't get a clear answer for in the documentation I visited.

1- In case I deployed a VM scale-set with auto-scaling and I had a VM that was scaled-in (according to the set policy) then it remained active for a while and after that, it was scaled-out after the utilization got back to normal. My question here is what happens to the data generated by the VM that was scaled in, then out (ex: logs) in case I was using Managed storage. Noting that the aim here is to persist important data (app logs...)?

2- As per what I understood from the documentation in order to update your app code for example (using SCM ex Git) on all the scale set nodes you will need the help of an automation tool (ex: ansible), or you'll need to update the custom image and redeploy it to the scale set. Is there a more centralized way that I missed?

3- Is there a way to add an existing VM to a new scale set other than converting it to a base image?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A1. If you do not set the persistent storage, then the scale in will just delete the instance without persisting the data in the VM.

A2. There is no other way to update your code, the best way is to change your VM image. Or use storage to store your code and then mount the storage to your VMSS. For example, the
Azure file share.

A3. No, you can't add other existing VMs to VMSS. It's impossible.

Comment: @NourShamaa Well, if it works for you please accept it.

Comment: @NourShamaa Is there any reason you don't accept it? Doesn't it work for you?